# Misunderstood jQuery's "undefined" trick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery uses this simple trick pattern :

```
(function( $ , window,undefined ) {

alert(window.aaa===undefined); //true

}(jQuery,window))
```

But  , as far as I understand it was made because a foolish person might do this :

```
undefined="lalala"
```

And then this should fail :

```
(function( $ , window ) {

alert(window.aaa===undefined);

}(jQuery,window))
```

[**but it doesn't**](http://jsbin.com/iculir/10/edit). ( *it alerts true*)

What am I missing?

Comment: Modern browsers do not let you assign to undefined, older ones still do. Switch IE to IE7/8 mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because modern browsers, like Google Chrome, have protection against setting the value of `undefined`:

[image]

This was introduced in ES5:

> `undefined` is non-writable, as per the ECMAScript 5 specification.

<sup>source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined</sup>

Comment: @RoyiNamir Kind of, but it's automatic. For example, try `undefined="lalala"; alert(undefined)` in JSBin and it will alert `undefined`.